# AWS Oracle RDS : Parameter group missing ENABLE_GOLDENGATE_REPLICATION

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, oracle-golden-gate

I'm attempting to implement replication between two AWS Oracle RDS instances using Golden Gate. So far it has not been a pleasant experience lol.

I'm currently stuck on enabling Golden Gate in the DB parameter group.  The "ENABLE_GOLDENGATE_REPLICATION" isn't available in the default group(s), adding a group doesn't make it available, and there is no option to add a KVP.

Comment: Are the RDS instances license-included or bring-your-own-license?

Comment: Add the oracle version and the edition you are using in the question.

Comment: Both license-included 
Source Engine = Oracle Standard Edition One 11.2.0.4.v4 
Destination Engine = Oracle Standard Edition One 11.2.0.4.v10

Comment: I was finally able to see this parameter by creating a new parameter group, setting the paging to 100, and using the filter.